# Is there a way I can call an event to a specific client rather than all of the connected clients using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Instead of emitting an event to all connected clients using io.emit(), I would like to just call an event to one client.

Comment: Did you notice `socket.emit(...)` in [the fine manual](http://socket.io/docs/)?

Comment: That emits the event to all clients, not one

Comment: Taking the [Express example](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4): `io.emit()` emits to all clients, `socket.emit()` emits to one client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the `socket` object for the particular client you want to send to and use:

```
someSocket.emit(...)
```

to just that one socket.  You will need to be able to get the appropriate socket for that one specific user.  You have not disclosed anything about how you app works for us to know how to recommend doing that.  Each socket has an `id` which can be looked up or you can keep your own index of each socket in your own data structure when they connect and disconnect.

To summarize: `io.emit()` sends to all connected users.  `someSocket.emit()` sends to just that one socket.

---

FYI, you don't "call an event to a specific client".  You can "send a message to a specific client".  Your client code can then register to be notified when that specific incoming message arrives.

Comment: @iii - Did this answer your question?